# How to correctly replace 'default_authentication_plugin' with 'authentication_policy'?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, authentication

I have MySQL 8.0.33 on Ubuntu. In the error log, I see the following warning:

> [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.

In my `mysql.cnf` file, I changed this line:

```
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

to this line:

```
authentication_policy= mysql_native_password
```

but it broke my application: when the application tries to connect to the database, it gets an error `Could not connect: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client.`

What is the correct way to solve this issue and remove the warning, without making too many changes to the application?

Comment: In what way exactly the change broke your application?

Comment: @mustaccio I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please elaborate what kind of error you got after

```
authentication_policy= mysql_native_password
```

// I just want to add, that this config works fine for me:

```
authentication_policy = CACHING_SHA2_PASSWORD
```

save this, and restart MySQL services with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: With only `mysql_native_password`, the server starts fine, but when the application  tries to connect, it gets an error message: `Could not connect: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. `.

With `caching_sha2_password, mysql_native_password` as you suggested, the server does not start at all: I get an error message `Option --authentication-policy is set to an invalid value. Please check if the specified authentication plugins are valid.`

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, Its working fine for me...
Just to make sure, this is what you wrote: "authentication_policy = caching_sha2_password, mysql_native_password"

not just one clause?

and if you did write both, what error/s did you get?

Comment: Yes, I wrote exactly as you wrote. And the error message I got was "Option --authentication-policy is set to an invalid value. Please check if the specified authentication plugins are valid."

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, I have made a change to the answer - Please update your .cnf file and tell if it works fine!

Comment: Now I get the previous error message while connecting: `Could not connect: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. `

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi,

Please try this: authentication_policy = MIXED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146422/discussion-between-dbafix-and-erel-segal-halevi).